# Garbage collection young generation scanning

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm trying to understand garbage collection mechanisms and I'm on generational algorithms and I have a question about young/old generation difference. I read that to start collecting objects in young generation GC is marking them starting from GC roots to find the live ones and usually it copies them to survivor space, clears young generation area and voila.

I don't get though if we start in GC roots and we start to go through live objects don't we find also object in old generation? Does it mean that when we hit an object in an old space we stop tracking references at that point or what?

Comment: The simple answer is Yes.  A young generation collection does not trace / mark objects in an older generation.  When the young generation collector finds a young-to-old reference, it ignores it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although I have not directly checked this, common sense dictates that the object graph traversal is curtailed each time an object from the Old Generation is encountered. Note that this check is very cheap to make: a simple range check on the pointer value suffices to determine object's placement within a heap region.

There is another vital point to consider, however: what if a young object is reachable only through an old object? Clearly, the Old Generation must be considered *somehow*.

Enter the **card table**: this is a backing structure in front of each heap region where a compressed "bitmap" view of the region is held, such that each bit corresponds to, say, 256 bytes of heap. Each time a reference-typed variable is updated, the corresponding bit in the card table is raised to 1, meaning "dirty".

With the card table in place, the following happens on each YG collection: all the chunks of heap marked as "dirty" are scanned for pointers to objects within the Young Generation. Each object found this way is considered reachable.

A corrolary of the above: young objects reachable through an old object which has in the meantime become garbage will be considered reachable and pollute the heap until a Major GC takes place.

Comment: Thanks Marko! You touched the topic of my next question - cards. Card area has a 256 bytes, but as I understand it it's a row memory, you need to know corresponding classes to make a sense out of it. So if we know memory area, how do we know what it holds or that it holds references at all? What else is there? :)

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the concern, but don't know the details. Memory could be scanned for a footprint of an object header, for example. When you know the header, you know the class. Also, each word may be *assumed* to be a pointer, then dereferenced to see if it points to a valid object header. This is heuristics, but it's probably "good enough".

Comment: I don't think it needs to be heuristic.  The JVM could iterate objects, based on the node size information in each object header.  Or it could record the address of the first object header in each card (or in a sequence of cards) and iterate based on that.

Comment: @StephenC Good points... recording the address of the first object does actually ring a bell for me. There is also some special handling for objects which span cards.

Comment: Any time the system touches an older-generation object it will know that it is doing so.  I would expect keeping a list of older-generation objects that have been touched would be cheaper than iterating through all of the older-generation objects.

Comment: @supercat There's a price to pay for knowing that it's doing so: each reference write must be encumbered with this logic. This is why the card table logic is executed regardless of which generation the object is in.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Upon some further consideration, I think the key observation is that the GC doesn't have to scan through all older objects and reconcile them with the card table--instead, if the GC encounters a reference to an older object, it can see if part of the object sits in a modified card and ignore the object if it doesn't.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I would think a framework could improve GC performance (especially on more constrained machines) if there were a means of declaring objects deeply immutable, since such objects wouldn't need card tables.

Answer (score 3):

When the GC run in Young Generation, it's called a Minor Collection. Objects in Old Generation are not concerned by this type of collection.

And yes objects directly reachable from the roots are marked as alive but they can be elsewhere in the heap so they can be objects in Old Generation.

Even if Old Gen object are reachable, minor collections won't reclaim garbage in Old Gen.

Quoting the [HotSpot doc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html) :

> When the young generation fills up it causes a minor collection in
>   which only the young generation is collected; garbage in other
>   generations is not reclaimed

For me it means that GC will go through the object graph, and maybe find garbage in OldGen but won't reclaim for it.

I've found this [IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp11253/) which explain quite well how intergenerational references tracking works in HotSpot GC.

Comment: But this is exactly my question, how is it possible, that Old Generation objects are not concerned by this type of collection? If they alive, they have to be referenced from GC roots, don't they?

Comment: Yes OldGen objects are reachable from roots. As Stephen C said, minor collections don't reclaim garbage in other generations, even if they are reachable.