# Do objects in Java memory ever get demoted from old to young for garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Edit - Warning before reading my question, I half-answer my own question in my edit below.

As far as I understand, the java garbage collector is split by generation because objects that survived garbage collection for a long time are likely to continue surviving because it means that those objects are crucial objects that continue to be referenced.

Therefore, until you reach your memory quota, the gc will only run on young and ignore the old.

Also, as far as I understand, the java gc starts from root and searches for objects referenced and marks the objects. And then it traverse through all the objects and frees all the objects that are not marked.

Now, my concern is what happens when the objects that the gc would go through to reach some object are all in old, but one of those intermediate objects has been modified.

For example, object A references B and both survived gc enough to be in old. To get to B, gc must go through A.

Also, B references C, but B gets modified to reference D instead. C is now trash that must be freed and D is a new object that's not trash. GC must go through B to reach D, and previously GC had to go through B to reach C.

My assumption here is that because B got modified, java checks if B exists in old, and if so, it gets demoted to young. And then every object that B references gets checked if they are in old and get demoted to young as well (and continue the demotion check for the children of those objects as well). (This, now, became pretty much like reference counting, so it's odd. Isn't the whole reason for mark-and-sweep to be so you don't go updating the reference counts each time an object is modified?)

But then here's the big problem. How does java know that A needs to be young as well? If you need to go through A to reach B, then A needs to be young as well. But B does not know that A is referencing B. What is done in this situation?

Edit:
[Garbage collection young generation scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280684/garbage-collection-young-generation-scanning?rq=1)

The above answers how instead of an object being demoted to young, when an object in old gets modified they get dirtied in a table. It's not super clear in that answer, but I assume the way it works is that when Minor GC runs, it not only starts from root, but it also starts from the dirtied object.

That, however, prompts a new question from me regarding circular references. The reason why circular references are not a concern for java gc is because gc starts from root and free everything not reachable from root. But if my assumption is correct, then, it means it would also start from a modified object, which then does mean you might have circular references that are marked that were not accessible from root. Maybe this isn't the biggest issue though because when you have to do Major GC, then you will only start from root, so those will get cleaned up during Major GC.

Comment: _My assumption here is that because B got modified, java checks if B exists in old, and if so, it gets demoted to young_: that assumption is wrong. Objects are never demoted from old to young. References from objects in the old generation to objects in the young generation are valid and handled correctly by the garbage collector.

Comment: If B stays old, how does GC ever reach D? This would mean D would always be cleaned by Minor GC since GC has to go through B to reach D and mark it, but Minor GC doesn't care about B because it is old

Comment: Regarding the new question about circular references: a minor GC doesn't reclaim all memory. Similar problems are for the C object (if it is already in the old generation) and for the B object if the reference from A to B is the only reference to B and it gets removed. These objects will the only be removed in the next major GC cycle. This is the price you have to pay when you want fast minor GCs.

Comment: Now your last paragraph renders the entire, quite long question before it pointless and asks an entirely different question. Which question should people answer? The long one they have to get through before learning that it has been answered already by yourself or the other, not even mentioned in the title one?

Comment: @ThomasKläger That's a good point, but I don't think that quite translates to what I was wondering. I can sorta see why that when both B and C are old and B gets removed, then C would be hanging until major GC. While I think it's a bit drastic, if that is how it works, I can still see it because after all C was old as well. But I guess I'm more curious about if and why something is the best decision (pros and cons) instead of just concluding as that's just how it is.

Comment: But this is the basic assumption of every multi-generation garbage collector: most objects die young, long lived objects stay alive. When doing a minor GC then it pays of to  only search the young space for live objects. To do this search you need the GC roots referring young objects and the set of old objects referring to young objects. Whether old objects are still alive or not is not a concern for the young generation collector - because if you start questioning whether old objects are still alive then you would need to traverse all objects.

Comment: Well, when your are “more curious about if and why something is the best decision (pros and cons)” you are even farther away from the question as written. You really should either, rewrite this question completely or remove this question and post a new one. I think, this is answerable if you ask the right question(s).

Answer (score -1):

Recommanded reading: [Java Garbage Collection Basics](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/Tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)

Java has a few different garbage collectors, they all work differently. But typically a mark phase will walk the object graph starting from roots (e.g. threads), objects that are reachable are marked, anything not marked will be cleared in the cleanup/sweep phase, in the case of minor GC, young gen space is cleaned. There is no need to move objects from old to young.